# SpringBoot project error in eclipse for Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

I have created a new SpringBoot application. But I see Errors in build path related to tomcat embed cannot be read or its valid zip.
Please find the screen shot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Does deleting the file from your local Maven repository (so that it will be downloaded again) fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks it worked now. Saved my time. Thank you